# grub install failing on SSD

Tags: linux, ssd, grub, ubuntu-18.04

I have a very frustrating problem. I wanted to set up a USB stick with a full install of Linux (I have gone for Zorin OS 15.1 but also have tried this with Ubuntu 18.04), that I could boot from any computer. I tend to use Macs so important that the drive has the right boot.efi setup so that simply holding down alt will provide the option to boot into it.

I followed the instructions here: https://medium.com/@mmiglier/ubuntu-installation-on-usb-stick-with-pure-efi-boot-mac-compatible-469ad33645c9 on a SanDisk Extreme Go USB 3.1 128GB drive and it worked perfectly. Really exciting, I can now boot into Zorin from any Mac.

I then went the whole way and bought a SanDisk Extreme Pro Portable SSD 500GB as the read speeds go to about 1050MB/s rather than the USB 150MB/s. I followed exactly the same steps but can never install grub.

The exact command is `sudo grub-install --target x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/boot --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id="$(lsb_release -ds)"`.

Time after time I get the error `grub-install: error: cannot find GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1. Check your device.map.`

I've researched the issue but cannot find anything specific to my case. I have tried GPT and MBR formatting. I have tried copying files from the working USB to the SSD e.t.c. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please append output of ```sudo blkid``` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the [Boot Repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) iso file.
2. Make a bootable Boot Repair live USB flash drive with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) or UNetbootin. If you have a Debian-based distribution handy you can also use Startup Disk Creator to make a bootable Boot Repair live USB flash drive.
3. Temporarily disconnect the cable(s) to the hard drive(s) on your host computer so that grub doesn't get installed on the wrong drive. You want grub to be installed on the SanDisk Extreme Pro portable SSD.
4. Boot from the Zorin/Ubuntu USB stick and install the OS until you get to the `grub-install: error` message. Continue the installation anyway until it finishes.
5. Reboot the computer with the bootable Boot Repair live USB flash drive selected as the first entry in the boot priority menu of the UEFI/BIOS.
6. Click the *Recommended repair* button in the Boot Repair menu and run it. You don't need to click any of the Advanced options. Boot Repair will install grub on the SanDisk Extreme Pro portable SSD.
7. Reboot to the Zorin/Ubuntu installer from its USB installation media.
8. At the *Installation type* screen select the *Replace **...** with Ubuntu/Zorin option* where **...** is whatever Linux you installed on the SanDisk SSD the last time. The installer may identify this Linux as "generic Linux" instead of Ubuntu because it has a different bootloader which was installed there by Boot Repair. This time the installer will run all the way through until the end and replace the grub that Boot Repair installed on the SanDisk Extreme Pro portable SSD with the appropriate grub for your distribution.
9. Reconnect the cable(s) to the hard drive(s) on your host computer.

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a shot. I am trying to install grub in an EFI compatible way, not sure if this will do it?

Comment: When I did it, it installed grub-efi-amd64 and it created a 537MB FAT32 EFI System partition at the beginning of the SSD adjacent to the ext4 partition on which Ubuntu 18.04 is installed.

Comment: So I tried this method and sadly could not get it to work, not sure if that is something I have not understood or my system e.t.c. I have finally settled on using refind.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a work around to this:

The trick is to install [refind](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) ***BUT*** make sure that when you install it the usb / ssd onto which you installed linux is connected.

What was happening was that I was installing refind and it wasn't detecting available linux partitions with standard grub. However, when a linux (ext4) partition is available at the time of installation, refind will install extra drivers so that it can find linux partitions in the future.

Not quite the solution to the original issue but gets the job done.